# How to sum the values of one property name based on sharing the value of another property name in an array of objects (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of hundreds of objects structured like:

```
[
        {
          "type": "apples",
          "count": 10
        },
        {
          "type": "oranges",
          "count": 20
        },
        {
          "type": "apples",
          "count": 5
        },
        {
          "type": "grapes",
          "count": 20
        },
        {
          "type": "grapes",
          "count": 10
        }
]
```

I need to loop through them and create a new array combining the counts if they share the same type. So output from above example would need to be:

```
[
        {
          "type": "apples",
          "count": 15
        },
        {
          "type": "oranges",
          "count": 20
        },
        {
          "type": "grapes",
          "count": 30
        },
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, javascript. Added tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use reduce. Note that this solution uses ES6 syntax.

```js
let values = [
        {
          "type": "apples",
          "count": 10
        },
        {
          "type": "oranges",
          "count": 20
        },
        {
          "type": "apples",
          "count": 5
        },
        {
          "type": "grapes",
          "count": 20
        },
        {
          "type": "grapes",
          "count": 10
        }
]

let collatedValues = values.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  let existing = accumulator.find(n => n.type === currentValue.type);
  if (existing) {
    existing.count += currentValue.count
  } else {
    accumulator.push(currentValue)
  }
  return accumulator
},[])

console.log(collatedValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
const data = [
  {
    type: 'apples',
    count: 10
  },
  {
    type: 'oranges',
    count: 20
  },
  {
    type: 'apples',
    count: 5
  },
  {
    type: 'grapes',
    count: 20
  },
  {
    type: 'grapes',
    count: 10
  }
];

const types = data.map((food) => food.type);
const uniqueTypes = [...new Set(types)];

const counts = uniqueTypes.map((foodType) => ({
  type: foodType,
  count: data
    .filter((food) => food.type === foodType)
    .map((food) => food.count)
    .reduce((acc, currCount) => acc + currCount, 0)
}));
```