# JS pull property from object in array and set to root level in array

Tags: javascript

I'm building off a prior question: [React displaying data in a table with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72764840/14330332)

In that question I was working on building a table to reflect the amount of hours worked for a client per day in a month (selected by the user, but the codesandbox I made is simplified). For another part of the app, I'm expanding that table so that an admin selects a user, month, and year and then the table populates the days of the month as the header, with each row being a different client. After a few steps, I have the output close to what I'm looking for, but 1 step shy and I'm stuck...

Heres the simplified data set and current logic:

```
const data = [
    {
    start: "2022-04-3",
    hours: 1,
    client: {
        id: "123",
      fullName: "Tom Tom"
    }
  },
  {
    start: "2022-04-10",
    hours: 2,
    client: {
        id: "123",
      fullName: "Tom Tom"
    }
  },
  {
    start: "2022-04-10",
    hours: 3,
    client: {
        id: "123",
      fullName: "Tom Tom"
    }
  },
  {
    start: "2022-04-10",
    hours: 1,
    client: {
        id: "123",
      fullName: "Tom Tom"
    }
  },
  {
    start: "2022-04-13",
    hours: 1,
    client: {
        id: "456",
      fullName: "Jack Jack"
    }
  },
  {
    start: "2022-04-13",
    hours: 2,
    client: {
        id: "123",
      fullName: "Tom Tom"
    }
  },
  {
    start: "2022-04-15",
    hours: 1,
    client: {
        id: "789",
      fullName: "Pete Pete"
    }
  },
  {
    start: "2022-04-15",
    hours: 1,
    client: {
        id: "789",
      fullName: "Pete Pete"
    }
  }
]

let collData = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { 
    let existing = accumulator.find((n) => n.client.id === currentValue.client.id && n.start === currentValue.start);
            if (existing) {
              existing.hours += currentValue.hours;
            } else {
              accumulator.push(currentValue);
            }
            return accumulator;
          }, []);
        console.log("step 1 ", collData);
        
        
let res = {};



collData.forEach((item) => {
    const splitDate = item.start.split("-");
    const day = splitDate[splitDate.length - 1];

    const newStat = { start: parseInt(day), hours: item.hours};
      
   if(res[item.client.id])
   {
       let stats = res[item.client.id].stats;
        stats = [...stats, newStat];
        res[item.client.id].stats = stats;
   }
   else{
      res[item.client.id] = {
        client: item.client,
        stats: [newStat]
      }
   }
    
  });


  let filtArr = [];
  
  const daysInMonth = 30;
 
    let dayInfo = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
      dayInfo.push(i)
 
      // create an array and fill hours with 0
 var dayArr = dayInfo.map((day) => ({
        day: day,
        hours: 0
      }));
      } 
      
const displayDates = (id) => {
  const client = res[id];

    let temp = [];
      dayArr.map((i, idx) => {
        const getHours = client.stats.find((item) => item.start === i.day);
        let newStats = {};
        if (getHours) {
          newStats = {
          
            client: {fullName: client.client.fullName, id: client.client.id},
            stats: [{
                day: i.day,
                hours: getHours.hours,
            }]
            
            
          };
      
        }
        else{
          newStats = {
            
            client: {fullName: client.client.fullName, id: client.client.id},
            stats: [{
                day: i.day,
            hours: 0,
            
            }]
            
          };
        }
        temp[idx] = newStats;
      });
 return temp;
      
}

 Object.keys(res).forEach(id=>{
    filtArr = [...filtArr, res[id]];
        console.log(displayDates(id))
  })
```

In order to map out the table rows/data, I'm trying to get the final data to be structured as: (currently client is being populated with each day of the month/hours)

```
current output = 
[{
  client: {
    fullName: "Pete Pete",
    id: "789"
 },
  stats: [{
    day: 1,
    hours: 0
   }]
 }, {
  client: {
    fullName: "Pete Pete",
    id: "789"
 },
  stats: [{
    day: 2,
    hours: 0
  }]
 }, {
  client: {
    fullName: "Pete Pete",
    id: "789"
 },
  stats: [{
    day: 3,
    hours: 0
  }]
 },//and so on for all days of the month
]

ideal output=
[
  {
    client: {name: "name name", id: "123"},
    stats: [
             {day: 1, hours: 0},
             {day: 2, hours: 1},
             {day: 3, hours: 0},
             {day: 4, hours: 2},
             //and so on for all the days in the month
            ]
  }
]
```

I've tried using map and forEach to get this structure, but I must not be understanding something about accessing the object properties in the array (I keep getting undefined errors). I figured there was probably somewhere in the logic along the way I could have structure it like this, but I'm not skilled enough to figure that out.
I have a JSFiddle with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/joznox/xzd5y142/3/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help off this site and they gave me a much cleaner working structure. In the end, it is a total rework of the patched together pieces I had put together before, but makes for a much more elegant solution. For anyone who comes along, here is the complete example:

```
 const data = [{
            start: "2022-04-3",
            hours: 1,
            client: {
                id: "123",
                fullName: "Tom Tom"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-10",
            hours: 2,
            client: {
                id: "123",
                fullName: "Tom Tom"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-10",
            hours: 3,
            client: {
                id: "123",
                fullName: "Tom Tom"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-3",
            hours: 3,
            client: {
                id: "123",
                fullName: "Tom Tom"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-10",
            hours: 1,
            client: {
                id: "123",
                fullName: "Tom Tom"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-13",
            hours: 1,
            client: {
                id: "456",
                fullName: "Jack Jack"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-13",
            hours: 2,
            client: {
                id: "123",
                fullName: "Tom Tom"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-15",
            hours: 1,
            client: {
                id: "789",
                fullName: "Pete Pete"
            }
        },
        {
            start: "2022-04-15",
            hours: 1,
            client: {
                id: "789",
                fullName: "Pete Pete"
            }
        }
    ]


var finalResult = (function (data, month, year) {
    
    let finalObject = {};
    var dateSet = [];
  
 
  
  const dataArr = data

    
    //Mapping the data set to something more manageable
    dataArr.forEach(x => {
        let clientObject = finalObject[x.client.id];

        if (!clientObject) {
            finalObject[x.client.id] = {
                clientName: x.client.fullName,
                id: x.client.id,
                stats: {}
            };
            clientObject = finalObject[x.client.id];
        }
        let currentDate = clientObject.stats[x.start];
        if (!currentDate) {
            clientObject.stats[x.start] = {};
        }
        
        clientObject.stats[x.start] = {
            start: x.client.start,
            hours: !currentDate?x.hours:currentDate.hours+x.hours
        };
    });

    //preparing the date sets
    for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
        dateSet.push(year + '-' + (month<9?"0"+month:month) + '-' + i);
    }

    // Composing the final data set
    Object.keys(finalObject).map(key=>{
        let currentClient = finalObject[key];
        let newStats = [];

        dateSet.forEach(date=>{
            var dateObject = currentClient.stats[date];
            newStats.push({
                start:date,
                hours:!dateObject?0:dateObject.hours
            });
        });
        
        currentClient.stats= newStats;
    });

    //console.log(Object.values(finalObject));
  return Object.values(finalObject)
 
})(data, 4, 2022)

console.log(finalResult)
```

which makes the output as follows, and sets it up to be easily mapped to table rows:

```
[{
  clientName: "Tom Tom",
  id: "123",
  stats: [{
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-1"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-2"
}, {
  hours: 4,
  start: "2022-04-3"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-4"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-5"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-6"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-7"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-8"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-9"
}, {
  hours: 6,
  start: "2022-04-10"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-11"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-12"
}, {
  hours: 2,
  start: "2022-04-13"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-14"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-15"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-16"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-17"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-18"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-19"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-20"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-21"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-22"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-23"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-24"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-25"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-26"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-27"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-28"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-29"
}]
}, {
  clientName: "Jack Jack",
  id: "456",
  stats: [{
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-1"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-2"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-3"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-4"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-5"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-6"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-7"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-8"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-9"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-10"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-11"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-12"
}, {
  hours: 1,
  start: "2022-04-13"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-14"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-15"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-16"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-17"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-18"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-19"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-20"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-21"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-22"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-23"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-24"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-25"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-26"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-27"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-28"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-29"
}]
}, {
  clientName: "Pete Pete",
  id: "789",
  stats: [{
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-1"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-2"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-3"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-4"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-5"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-6"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-7"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-8"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-9"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-10"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-11"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-12"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-13"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-14"
}, {
  hours: 2,
  start: "2022-04-15"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-16"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-17"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-18"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-19"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-20"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-21"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-22"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-23"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-24"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-25"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-26"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-27"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-28"
}, {
  hours: 0,
  start: "2022-04-29"
}]
}]
```